# No code run after accessing arrays/lists

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, shared, public

I am literally stumped on this one...

When running my code, the program just... doesn't run the rest of the code after I attempt to do anything with arrays or lists within in form load event, here's my code:

```
Public Shared alerts As String()

Private Sub Popup_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height)
    ' Check for alerts
    If My.Settings.hasadmin = False Then
        MsgBox("test1")
        pb_alert.Visible = True
        createAlert("Some functions require admin privileges.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub createAlert(ByVal msg As String)
    MsgBox("test2")
    updateAlerts()
    MsgBox("test5")
End Sub

Private Sub updateAlerts()
    MsgBox("test3")
    Dim length = alerts.Length
    MsgBox("test4")
End Sub
```

I don't know why this is happening...

Messageboxes coming up are:
"test1"
"test2"
"test3"
then nothing, because I accessed the alerts array?

I have no clue, help please!

ALSO I see no errors or compiling problems or ANYTHING!

The program continues after this, but it just won't bring up the other message boxes, which I want to replace with actual code of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that an exception is being thrown because `alerts` is `Nothing`.

The easy way around this is to initialize the string with a -1 size so that it is an empty array.

```
Public Shared alerts As String(-1)
```

The correct way is to test for Nothing before attempting to use it.

```
If alerts IsNot Nothing Then
  ' Do something with it
```

The other thing that you must do is add exception handling to the load event or add a [AppDomain unhandled exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) or handle the [WinforsFormsApplicaBase UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.unhandledexception.aspx).

```
Load event:

Try
Catch theException As Exception
  Call MsgBox(theException.Message)
End Try
```